# OnActivityResult crash if I choose a large image

Tags: android, android-activity, android-image

I have to get the image path of images in the gallery, to save it a list, unfortunately if the selected image is too large the following code crashes the app (and the alerts in my try catch block aren't viewed).

```
private void openImage() {

         try{
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(i, FILE_REQ_CODE);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
               Alerts.TooLargeImage(LoadImage.this);
            }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intentData) {
        try{
            Uri tmp = intentData.getData();
            String path = tmp.toString();
            imagePathList.add(path);
            preview.setImageURI(tmp);
            FileArchiveManager.saveImagePath(imagePathList);
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
               Alerts.TooLargeImage(LoadImage.this);
            }
    }
```

The error log

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=8135KB, Allocated=3718KB, Bitmap Size=11707KB)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:694)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:494)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:657)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:592)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:313)
    at com.myapp.LoadImage.onActivityResult(LoadImage.java:131)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3016)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3072)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1084)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));
```

Using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` and `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` will allow you to load a downsampled version of the Bitmap into RAM (because you realistically won't need such a large image to display) without causing `java.lang.OutofMemoryError`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I haven't understand how to use your code in my method

Comment: the app crash with java.io.EOFException and doesn't show neither the gallery if I try to use setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100)); in onActivityResult

Comment: Can you give me more details on the EOFException?

Comment: The problem seems in get the getResources(). How could I get the resource from Uri tmp?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android 3.0 onward use bellow code within application tag in manifest file

application
        android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, if you wish to help the person.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem i just used **Glide**. i required 640x640 image as output from any 1:1 ratio image code:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  Uri selectedImage = result.getUri();
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(selectedImage).override(640,640).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
      bitmap = resource;
      logoImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
  });
}
```

> Tested with Maximum 40mb image file